# width of original image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

quick question.

I am trying to find the width and height of the stored image on the server so I can load this into a jcrop feature.

The image shown on the page is resizable so does not represent the propper size of the original image, so whne I try to jcrop it, the co-oredinates are wrong

Is there any way to find the original height and width using jquery or javascript.

UPDATE

I have made a jsfiddle of something I need that doesnt work, can anyone see why it doesnt work http://jsfiddle.net/2C2Eu/2/

code

```
function getimagesize(img) {
img.onload = function () {
    alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
};
}

var image = "http://www.citizenship-aei.org/wp-content/uploads/Testing.jpg";
getimagesize(image);
```

Comment: What does your code look like? Can you not just add attributes to your img tag with the original dimensions?

Comment: @putvande I never store the original image dimensions. I am sending the filepath of the image to a function. In the function I am then showing the image on a pop up with a jcrop option to crop the image. Currently I am sending the height and width of the image to the function, but these are the height and width of the resized image. I want the dimensions of the original image. I cant post the code as theres several thousand lines and it would take me several hours to chop it up to show you the relevant parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function GetAnImage(src) {

    var newImg = document.createElement('img');
    newImg.src = src;

    return newImg;
}

var newImg = GetAnImage("abc.jpg");
newImg.onload = function () {                           
    var height = this.height;
    var width = this.width;  
    //do with the image as you want         
}
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: Why did you select this over mine? Just curious since it is the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Load the image on the page and read the dimensions.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;
    processImage(img, width, height); //call some function
}
img.src = "foo.png";
```

Comment: I was just creating an example when I checked back to find you'd had answered. http://jsfiddle.net/2C2Eu/

Comment: I have already loaded the image and resized it according to the stored resized dimensions. This is after the page has loaded, I send the filepath to a function on a popup page

Comment: @Gavin I ahve updatyed your fiddle with something I need, but obviously I cant get it to work, thats why I posted the question, please take a look and see if you can help http://jsfiddle.net/2C2Eu/2/

Comment: @BarryWatts There is no onload with a string!

Comment: @BarryWatts - http://jsfiddle.net/2C2Eu/3/ - I've updated the fiddle, however just to make you aware, you cannot use this as a `var imgSize = getImageSize('http://path.to.img.jpeg');` as the loading of the image is asynchronous. However, you can use callbacks, as I have, so you can get the image dimensions and then do something with them once they are available.